# How to filter based on a property of the current object?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of file objects like this:

```
{"name":"A1.java", "analyze":false, "index":0},
{"name":"A2.java", "analyze":true, "index":1},
{"name":"A3.java", "analyze":false, "index":2}
```

I'm trying to show the file names that have `"analyze":true`. I think it needs to be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  {{m.files.name | filter: m.files.analyze == true}}
</div>
```

But this is not giving me an error, and it's not showing anything.

**Edit:** I know there are many ways to do this, but I am specifically interested in **filtering**. If your answer doesn't involve filtering or why it can't be done with filtering, please don't bother, I already know how to do it *other* ways.

Comment: use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives to achieve this.

Comment: I'm trying to learn the inline filtering capabilities of angular. If I wanted to do it that way I would have used `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @TravisHeeter Do you want to filter based on some user action? i.e. select an option from a dropdown, which in turn applies the filter?

Comment: @frishi Yes, basically radio buttons that allow the user to check which files to analyze. Checking/Unchecking the radio button changes analyze to true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-repeat with a filter to show all rows that qualify, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="file in m.files | filter: {analyze: true}">
  {{ file.name }}
</div>
```

Or, if you want to simply evaluate m.files for a condition like analyze = true, you can create a custom filter, like this

```
app.filter('fileFilter', function() {

  return function(files) {
    var result = false;
    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
      if (file.analyze) {
        result = true;
      }
    });

    return result;

  };

});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div ng-show="(m.files | filter:fileFilter)">
```

Comment: OK, this is the closest so far, but what about when I only want to show all the files selected if they're not all selected? In other words, how can I use this filter in other situations like `ng-show`? For instance, `ng-show="m.files | filter {analyze: true} < m.files.length"`

Comment: @TravisHeeter - Ok, I better understand what your asking now.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Actually the filter doesn't seem to be working: `<div ng-init="files = m.files | filter: ff">{{files.length}}</div>` is showing `0`.

Comment: @TravisHeeter - the filter you were asking for was in the context of ng-show so I wrote it to return a bool.  In the use case you're now mentioning you'd need to return filtered data object from the filter.

Comment: OK, perhaps something that your answer missed was that each file object has an `analyze` property. `fileFilter` only returns `true` or `false`. I was wanting all the files where `analyze` was `true`. Your answer would have worked if I was inside a `ng-repeat`, and wanted to check analyze for each file individually. Honestly though, your first section answers the question, so I'll just update the second part to show what I needed in order to use the filtered array outside an ng-repeat. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function PersonalFilter(data){

    return (data.analyze)? data.name:"";

}

    app.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return PersonalFilter;
    });


<div class="row">
  {{m.files | myFilter}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way to do this with filtering?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have read your comment after posting my solution. I have changed the solution. Check if this solution it's ok for you.